# how to properly scrape a web page with R

Tags: html, asp.net, r

can anyone give me some hints on how to properly scrape this web page (asp with passing parameters:
http://statistiche.terna.it/statistiche/regioni.asp?ANNO=2013&AREA=Veneto)

my rough attempt is the following and I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way to deal with it (as you can see the poor result, among other things, is mismataching the rows)

thanks

```
library(XML)

aaaa<-2013

url<-paste0("http://statistiche.terna.it/statistiche/regioni.asp?ANNO=", aaaa, "&AREA=Veneto")

tmp<-readHTMLTable(url, which=1, as.data.frame=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

head(tmp, 25)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try out `rvest` package with SelectorGadget?

This gives results, but it somehow doesn't read the negative numbers. You can find a way out for that:

```
web.html <- html("http://statistiche.terna.it/statistiche/regioni.asp?ANNO=2013&AREA=Veneto")
web.html_href <- web.html %>%
html_nodes("#DataTable") %>%
html_table(header = FALSE, fill = T)

web.html_href
```

Comment: in fact that specific variable was not of much interest (at least to me) because it was simply a percentage over two previous variables;

 so I did not bother too much with that problem but I'll try to understand how to for a more general interest;

thank you again for pointing me to "rvest": I'm a bit challenged how to properly deal with SelectorGadget (not completely clear how it works in the selection of the gadget to be extracted)